# How to to schedule a Job (not a CronJob) to an future date?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I need that a Job on Kubernetes run in an future date. Its important to be a Job, not a CronJob, because it needs to run only once.

For example, after creating this Job, it is ran immediately. How i schedule it to run on some date in the future?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: do-something
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: do-something
        image: do-something
        command: ["python",  "/app/do-something.py"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Comment: Create a CronJob that, as part of its execution, deletes itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the way one should use Job, for scheduled jobs you should use cronjobs.

A CronJob creates Jobs on a repeating schedule. [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

however you can use a job and trigger it with other CRDs like argoCD.
For example we trigger a job with each argocd sync.
Please provide more information so we can tailor something for your specific need : )